# Missing external_id in item.update web hook event

Tags: webhooks, podio

We're not seeing external ID included in item.update webhook. [The documentation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks) says we should be included:

> item.update: When an item is updated. Provides parameter "item_id", "item_revision_id" and "external_id".

The parameters we do see (via requestbin) are:

```
item_id: 12345
hook_id: 9875
type: item.update
item_revision_id: 2
```

What do we need to do to have external_id included in the webhook event? Or am I misreading the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podio documentation is up-to-date and `external_id` parameter is sent for  `item.create` and `item.update` hooks. In order to have it sent, item needs to have it :)

So, if you just create item from Podio web, that item won't have any `external_id`. But if you create item via API and specify external_id then it will be there.
Here is full example in **Ruby**:

```
attr = {:fields => { :title => 'Created with external ID'},
        :external_id => 'exernal_id_for_demo' }
item = Podio::Item.create(app_id, attr)
```

Then webhook `item.create` will be:

```
item_id: 720040614
item_revision_id: 0
type: item.create
hook_id: 7243151
external_id: exernal_id_for_demo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Podio provide external_id with the hook data. What you should do is do another call '[Get item revision difference](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374)' with item_revision_id as the revision_to_id. This will give you the current revision details. And you can find the external_id and field_id in this response.

Comment: Thank you - I guess the documentation is out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than receive the external_id, we can register a hook to be triggered only against a particular field. This way, the URL that's triggered can encode which external_id was involved.

The gotcha is that you can't do this from the management interface, but you can from the API. For example, using HTTPie, if we had a field with an id of 123...

```
 http POST https://api.podio.com/hook/app_field/123/ \
    url=http://your.endpont/123 
    type=item.update 
    'Authorization: OAuth2 token-here'
```

...which returns the hook_id, and you'd validate the hook as usual.

Via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39782472/154248